# Continuously Fire like machine gun

Tags: unity, c#

[image: <code>[![Something happen like this][1]][1]</code>]I made the game space shooter and i want the space fire continuously (auto fire) without click the button. [ This are the code i always click on space bar and its fire but i want its fire continuously (auto fire). if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isEnemyWeapon == false) { Fire (); } ] and i want only player fire continuously not enemy. In my case enemy also fire continuously like laser after taking some times..

Weapon.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform laserPrefab ;
    public bool isEnemyWeapon = false;
    public float shootDelay = 0.0f;
    private float waitToShoot;

    void Start () {
        waitToShoot = 0f;
    }

    void Update () {

        if (waitToShoot > 0) {
         waitToShoot = Time.deltaTime;      

        }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isEnemyWeapon == false) {
          Fire ();
    }   

        if (isEnemyWeapon == true && EnemyAttack == false) {
            waitToShoot = shootDelay;
            var shootLaser = Instantiate (laserPrefab) as Transform;
            Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
            pos.x = transform.position.x ;
            pos.y = transform.position.y - 0.3f;
            shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
            SoundHelper.instanceSound.EnemyLaserSound();

        }
    }


    public void Fire()
    {
        var shootLaser = Instantiate(laserPrefab) as Transform;
        Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
        pos.x = transform.position.x;
        pos.y = transform.position.y + 0.5f;
        shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.PlayerLaserSound();


    }

public bool EnemyAttack
    {
         get
        {
         return waitToShoot <= 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code which should work for you:

```
bool firingContinously = false; // is firing right now
float nextFire = 0; // when the next bullet fires
float fireDelay = 100; // 100 milliseconds between each bullet, you can change that

void Update(){
    if(firingContinously && !isEnemyWeapon)
    {
        if(Time.time * 1000 > nextFire){
            nextFire = (Time.time * 1000) + fireDelay; // delay the next fire by the fireDelay
            Fire();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to fire continously, you change `firingContinously` to `true`, and to stop - you change it to `false`.

I didn't test it. Copy the `Update()` method contents into your `Update()` method and these `3 variables` somewhere to your class so it looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform laserPrefab ;
    public bool isEnemyWeapon = false;
    public float shootDelay = 0.0f;
    private float waitToShoot;

    public bool firingContinously = false;
    float nextFire = 0;
    float fireDelay = 100; // 100 milliseconds between each bullet


    void Start () {
        waitToShoot = 0f;
    }

    void Update () {


        if(firingContinously && !isEnemyWeapon)
        {
            if(Time.time * 1000 > nextFire){
                nextFire = (Time.time * 1000) + fireDelay;
                Fire();
            }
        }


        if (waitToShoot > 0) {
         waitToShoot = Time.deltaTime;      

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isEnemyWeapon == false) {
              Fire ();
        }   

        if (isEnemyWeapon == true && EnemyAttack == false) {
            waitToShoot = shootDelay;
            var shootLaser = Instantiate (laserPrefab) as Transform;
            Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
            pos.x = transform.position.x ;
            pos.y = transform.position.y - 0.3f;
            shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
            SoundHelper.instanceSound.EnemyLaserSound();

        }
    }


    public void Fire()
    {
        var shootLaser = Instantiate(laserPrefab) as Transform;
        Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
        pos.x = transform.position.x;
        pos.y = transform.position.y + 0.5f;
        shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.PlayerLaserSound();


    }

public bool EnemyAttack
    {
         get
        {
         return waitToShoot <= 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Spectre, I applied your code and i test it but the enemy and player both are not firing now.

Comment: I'll be home and fix it in 10-15 minutes :)

Comment: `nextFire += fireDelay;` Here's an error (mine). We want to set the delay to currentTime + fireDelay. So it should be: `nextFire = (Time.time * 1000) + fireDelay;` I'll edit the code. You try it out.

Comment: I am able to fire now but continuously fire not working (for fire still i pressed the space_bar).

Comment: That's why you have a `firingContinously` variable. Change it to true and check what happens :)

Comment: I change it too true. But not working!!

Comment: Please put this `Debug.Log("Fire Method");` in your `Fire()` function and check if it runs

Comment: Sorry its not happening. please provide me your mail id. So, I contact with u there with my problems

Comment: Get to the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63653/spectres-room

Comment: Sorry Spectre i don't have 20 Reputation right now so i am unable to chat with u :(

Comment: I mailed u spectre!! check its from ~ Kunal

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not have one class for both your enemy weapon and your player weapon. Create a separate class for each of them. And having a base class could be a good idea too :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform laserPrefab ;
    public float shootDelay = 0.1f;
    protected float nextFireTime;

    public abstract bool CanShoot
    {
        get;
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        nextFireTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if ( CanShoot )
        {
            Fire ();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Fire()
    {
        nextFireTime = Time.time + shootDelay;
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerWeapon : Weapon {

    public override bool CanShoot
    {
        get { return Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time >= nextFireTime  ; }
    }

    public override void Fire()
    {
        base.Fire();
        var shootLaser = Instantiate(laserPrefab) as Transform;
        Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
        pos.x = transform.position.x;
        pos.y = transform.position.y + 0.5f;
        shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.PlayerLaserSound();
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyWeapon : Weapon {

    public override bool CanShoot
    {
        get { return Time.time >= nextFireTime ; }
    }

    public override void Fire()
    {
        base.Fire();
        var shootLaser = Instantiate (laserPrefab) as Transform;
        Vector2 pos = shootLaser.transform.position;
        pos.x = transform.position.x ;
        pos.y = transform.position.y - 0.3f;
        shootLaser.transform.position = pos;
        SoundHelper.instanceSound.EnemyLaserSound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Hellium, i try your code too but its not work!!

Comment: What does not work ? You have to create 3 scripts : `Weapon`, `PlayerWeapon` and `EnemyWeapon`. Attach `PlayerWeapon` to your player gameobject, `EnemyWeapon` to your enemy and specify the correct values for `laserPrefab` and `shootDelay`.

Comment: I made an edit an hour ago in the `CanShoot` property, make sure you have the correct one. And change the protection level of  `nextFireTime`

Comment: I just have tested the scripts I gave you, it works fine.

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you so much Hellium for helping me :)